# SimpleITK cannot show image

Tags: python, image, medical, simpleitk, medical-imaging

I have below code. `print(image.GetDimension())` works and prints the output `(512, 512, 17)`. But `sitk.Show(image)` doesn't work.

**My Code**

```
import SimpleITK as sitk

path = "C:/Users/myUserName/Desktop/0001.DCM"
image = sitk.ReadImage(path)

print(image.GetDimension())
sitk.Show(image)
```

My error message is:

```
RuntimeError: Exception thrown in SimpleITK Show: D:\a\1\sitk\Code\IO\src\sitkImageViewer.cxx:562:
sitk::ERROR: Error in administrating child process: [Access is denied].
Command line: 'C:\Users\myUserName\Fiji.app' 'C:\\Users\\myUserName\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\TempFile-21536-2.mha'
```

How can I fix that? I have unzipped ImageJ and put the `Fiji.app` folder at `C:\Users\myUserName\Fiji.app`. The DICOM image `0001.DCM` has no problem as I can view it via some online DICOM viewer. I am using Windows 10, and run my Python code in Spyder. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens when you paste the command line into a shell prompt to try and run it by hand?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In Windows' cmd, I tried to run `> python` to enter the python environment, and then run the first line `import SimpleITK as sitk`, then I got the error message `C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:143: UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service`. And then I typed `exit()` to exit .

Comment: I also tried to run `> python myPythonCode.py` in cmd directly, and then I have the same error message `C:\Users\myUserName\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:143`... blahblahblah. Any ideas?

Comment: the mkl-service package isn't installed in your anaconda environment.  you can install it like this:  conda install -c conda-forge mkl-service

Comment: @DaveChen Thanks for your reply. I just tried to do it in cmd, and installed mkl-service as you advised. But the error message is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the SITK_SHOW_COMMAND to point directly to the ImageJ executable.  For your installation of Fiji, the environment variable should be set to C:\Users\myUserName\Fiji.app\ImageJ-win64.exe.

OK, here's my slightly modified version of your script:

```
import SimpleITK as sitk

#path = "C:/Users/myUserName/Desktop/0001.DCM"
path = "C:\SimpleITK-build\SimpleITK-build\ExternalData\Testing\Data\Input\DicomSeries\Image0075.dcm"
image = sitk.ReadImage(path)

print(image.GetDimension())
sitk.Show(image, debugOn=True)
```

The only difference is that I added the debugOn flag to the call to Show.

And here's my output:

```
Debug: In D:\bld\libsimpleitk_1627514864077\work\Code\IO\src\sitkImageViewer.cxx, line 495: ExecuteCommand: 'C:/Users/dchen/Fiji.app/ImageJ-win64.exe' '-eval' 'open("C:\\Users\\dchen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\TempFile-10808-0.mha"); rename("C:\\Users\\dchen\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\TempFile-10808-0.mha");'


Debug: In D:\bld\libsimpleitk_1627514864077\work\Code\IO\src\sitkImageViewer.cxx, line 576: Done.  Deleting process.
```

And you can see exactly the command that SimpleITK is executing to invoke Fiji.  In particular, the program being launched is 'C:/Users/dchen/Fiji.app/ImageJ-win64.exe'.

If you turn on the debugOn flag, what does SimpleITK output?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried to do `$SITK_SHOW_COMMAND = "C:\Users\myUserName\Fiji.app\ImageJ-win64.exe"` in my PowerShell, and confirmed that the variable is set using `Get-Variable -Name SITK_SHOW_COMMAND`. I can also confirm that the file `C:\Users\myUserName\Fiji.app\ImageJ-win64.exe` exists. But I still have the same error when running the Python code.

Comment: I tried `setx SITK_SHOW_COMMAND "C:\Users\myUserName\Fiji.app\ImageJ-win64.exe"` in cmd instead, and it works!. Now the ImageJ pop up and the problem it solved. I have no idea why `$SITK_SHOW_COMMAND = ` in PowerShell doesn't work but `setx` in cmd works. But the problem is now anyway solved. Thanks!!